# Using Windows 7, how can you use multiple mice (to get multiple cursors)?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Is it somehow possible to use two mice in Windows 7? I think this could be useful; like using two fingers on a multi touch display...

Comment: Related: [Why can't I use two or more keyboards/mice at the same time on one computer?](http://superuser.com/questions/135922)

Comment: Microsoft Research article referring to this idea: [MultiPoint](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/india/projects/edulab/multipoint.html)

Answer (score 17):

yes, you can use two mice in MS Windows and have two cursors - if you like.

just check out **EitherMouse**  http://www.eithermouse.com

Freeware, no ads, no nags.

it works on Windows XP, Vista, 7, 8.

individual settings:

- multi-cursor
- swap buttons
- mirror cursors
- set mouse speed
- set double click speed
- set scroll wheel lines

Comment: what about win10?

Comment: You can't move two mice at the same time with this. It draws a mouse cursor on screen and leaves it there when the other mouse starts moving and picks up from there when the other mouse starts moving again.

Comment: Marked as virus by Trend Micro...

Comment: Chrome gives this warning: The site ahead contains harmful programs
Attackers on www.eithermouse.com might attempt to trick you into installing programs that harm your browsing experience.

Comment: [VirusTotal: 38/66](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/588d26136557cd724b6a18c918758f4a4a22b77373d5e69b25274f7b4be63c7a/detection) virus scanner detect this as malware

Answer (score 15):

You're looking for [TeamPlayer](http://www.dicolab.com/products/teamplayer).

Comment: Correct link seems to be [here](http://dicolab.com/).  I have no idea if it works, since it's not free - though a tool like this really should be...

Comment: This one actually works. However, in my case, the effective mouse input update/refresh rate was reduced when I used it.

Comment: If you're just looking for two, for noncommercial use, [this](https://www.dicolab.com/getfreetp4liteform.html) is the right link.

Comment: Domain is dead...

Answer (score 14):

I haven't tried it myself but [Pluralinput](http://pluralinput.com/) looks to be another option.

Comment: this is buggy but is beta in active development, this will have a nice future :)

Comment: This didn't work for me with Windows 8; it thought both mice were just one mouse.

Comment: This worked for me after a reboot in Windows 7. Its a little buggy but works. Developer needs to add an option to flip the mouse image!

Comment: @sam are you sure?

Comment: @JoséRobertoAraújoJúnior it doesn't seem to be in active development anymore

Comment: @Menasheh, That was 3 years ago, so I can't remember the details now! :)

Comment: Download pages are unavailable...

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft Touch SDK has this functionality.

Maybe [this project](https://github.com/nesherhh/MultiTouchVista) on GitHub will be helpful.

Comment: This appears to treat multiple mice as multiple touches on a touch-screen, rather than multiple separate mouse pointers.  I can't imagine a scenario where that would be useful.

Comment: @BlueRaja: It's a nice solution for multitouch developers who doesn't have multitouch screen...

Comment: I don't think this is of much use to end-users.

Answer (score 7):

I have been using two mice alternating (one on each side of my keyboard) for ergonomic reasons. Windows 7 allowed for this just fine for 2 years until a month ago or so, That is when the one on the left started to execute a double click if I clicked once. It also highlighted a whole word if I only wanted to place the cursor in a certain spot.

I asked my office professional for another mouse to check if this was a hardware issue - Nope! Same thing again. 
That's when I ran into **EitherMouse** and downloaded it. Alas, life is good again! No more crazy mouse behaviour.

Comment: Is http://www.eithermouse.com/ what you're referring to? I guess as a new user, you might not be able to post such link. But also, your post smells *a little bit* like spam. But that links seems to be freeware?

Comment: This does not address the question on how to have multiple cursors.

Comment: The website doesn't currently load for me, but from a cached Google version, it indicates that it just allows separate configuration (not use) for each mouse.

Comment: @AthomSfere: Well, it does support multiple cursors. I've just downloaded the latest version and played in "Multi-Cursor" mode. It's almost working :)

Comment: @dma_k Nice! I just looked at the site again and I do not see mention of that... But downloaded and confirmed!

Comment: EitherMouse indeed works, but not well, for me.  The 2 mice would summon each other back to the same position. PluralInput gave me a mouse that can't drag windows. TeamPlayer4 gave me mice that worked well, but the side-buttons which I control through a different 3rd party program no longer work. No perfect solution for me. :)

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for collaborative screen sharing with two mice - found [Screenhero](http://screenhero.com) .  Free for now as it is in beta.  Good times.

Comment: Woah that actually looks really cool, I'm impressed.

Comment: Well, one needs to have two PCs and one is connecting to another (like [Multimouse in post above](http://superuser.com/a/161010/28311)). What the question is about: can one connect two mouses or keyboards to one PC and use them independently?

Comment: @dma_k You're absolutely right, maybe I should have added this as a comment rather than an answer.  My bad.

Comment: The domain redirects to another...

Comment: I wonder why it's now specifically Slack.

Answer (score 4):

I Considered all of the above Apps that claim to do this task.
The BEST, most TRANSPARENT, USER FRIENDLY, SMALL LEARNING CURVE app was [Plural Input](http://pluralinput.com/)

Currently in Beta Version but very good.

1. Download and Install Plural Input
2. Make sure [Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653) is installed too.
3. Install Plural Input Drivers over your existing additional mouse driver under: Control Panel >> Device Manager >> Mice & other pointing devices.
4. You will find the Driver under C:\Program Files (x86)\Pluralinput\Driver
5. Install Correct Driver! Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 have their own 32 and 64 bit driver
6. Setup Plural input
7. Run Plural Input

Comment: Hello Verus and welcome to Superuser. Unfortunatly your answer is the same as [Danny](http://superuser.com/a/498520/50173)'s. If you have something to contribute, please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/498520/edit) the existing answer

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this works, but [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/39571-two-mice-two-cursors-in-autoit/) is an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) script that claims to allow two cursors at once from two separate mice.

Comment: The author says in the code comments that clicking isn't possible, so this probably isn't of much real world value.

Answer (score 2):

Download the free [GlovePIE](http://glovepie.org/glovepie.php). Its website states:

> You can even use it to control multiple mouse pointers with multiple mice.

Comment: The site has gone...

Comment: Everything is forbidden...

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft Multi-Point SDK (http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-sdk/ , for people who have basic developer/math skills) or Mouse Mischief (http://www.microsoft.com/multipoint/mouse-mischief/en-us/default.aspx) for those who are teachers. P.S. never can you have two mouse cursors because usually the application draws them not the windows OS. I am researching this for my Kinect project here which will emulate multiple mice device and input to them from multiple Kinect users: http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com. Keep checking up on it because I am researching a better method then Microsoft's DSF(Device simulation framework)  to do so. For the most part, the Kinect code is close to working but I am still working on the mouse simulation part.

Comment: I know this is old but I have a mouse emulator I am working on which will allow anyone to distribute my project for anyone still interested.

Comment: `never can you have two mouse cursors because usually the application draws them not the windows OS` is a non-sequitur. If each app draws its cursor then each app just draws its cursor. It's like saying you can't have two windows because each app draws its windows.