# Can I use a second keyboard to generate particular keystrokes?

Tags: usb, keyboard, keystrokes

The solution may be otherwise, but the question itself is quite simple: Is there anything (software, a relatively easy way to develop it, or anything) that can allow me to plug a second USB keyboard and assign specific keystrokes to it?

By the way, my goal is to have some kind of a "buttons panel" for [Microsoft Flight Simulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator) for really cheap.

Note: I've already seen those posts:

- [Changing the keystrokes of a USB keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/185436/changing-the-keystrokes-of-a-usb-keyboard)
- [Why can't I use two or more keyboards/mice at the same time on one computer?](https://superuser.com/questions/135922/why-cant-i-use-two-or-more-keyboards-mice-at-the-same-time-on-one-computer)

But if they are quite interesting, there aren’t any proposed solutions. It would seem crazy to me that with everything we can do in one click with a computer nowadays, we could not use a second keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally found a solution: [HID Macros](http://www.hidmacros.eu/whatisit.php). Though it's closed source, it is freeware, and it appears to do exactly what I want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It now says *"HidMacros is dead. Welcome LuaMacros"*.

Comment: HID Macros was [allegedly](http://www.hidmacros.eu/) [open sourced](https://github.com/me2d13/hidmacros) at the end of 2014.