# Two Mice/Pointers at once on one computer?

Tags: mouse, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using two mice in Windows 7 (dual mouse, dual cursor)](https://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor)

Is there a way to have two mice controlling two separate pointers on one computer?