# Can two mice and two keyboards be locked to two different windows?

Tags: windows-7, multiseat, multiple-users

Basically what [this question](https://superuser.com/q/29432/35237) asks for, however I want to be able to asign one pair of inputs to one single window (and if possible also redirect only the applications sound output to the front plug or to the rear channel whichever is easier), so basically I seek "multiseat lite"

Comment: Same question for Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/5511/863

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking about a multiseat system, where more than one monitor, keyboard, and mouse are connected to one computer, but have separate workstations?

If so, [MiniFrame](http://www.miniframe.com/) offers this, as well as [ThinSoft](http://www.thinsoftinc.com/index.aspx), and [Aster](http://international.ibik-soft.com/content/view/77/).

([Source](http://endlessparadigm.com/forum/showthread.php?tid=17456)).

Comment: thanks for your answer. To be honest, I forgot about this question since I received answers to a [similar question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/14202/88) at gaming.SE with the result being using Virtual Box with a trapped keyboard/mouse, but I'll try your links as well