# OSX or Windows - 2 independent mice on a single computer?

Tags: mouse

I'm looking for a driver or something to give me 2 independent mouse pointers controlled by two mice plugged into one computer.

Think multi-touch type thing without the touch.

Comment: For X11, not Windows or OS X: http://multicursor-wm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Any particular reason? I.e. what problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the questions/answers at [Multi Mouse & Keyboard for Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5874/multi-mouse-keyboard-for-mac) (on Apple.SE):

- It can't be done on a Mac.
- The Windows solution is [Windows MultiPoint Server](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/), but that's geared towards schools.

Another similar question is [Using two mice in Windows 7 (dual mouse, dual cursor)](https://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor), where the answers included:

- [CPNMouse](http://cpnmouse.sourceforge.net/)
- [Dual Mouse & keyboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dualmousekeyboa/)
- [Multimouse for Windows 7](http://www.windows7download.com/win7-multimouse/ztjjgcdq.html)
- [TeamPlayer](http://www.wunderworks.com/teamplayer/)

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions:

1. Sample code for a solution: [Stack Overflow - Multiple mice on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854185/multiple-mice-on-os-x)
2. A program to give you two pointers: [Dual OS X](http://www.dualosx.com/)