# Two pointing devices, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse, tablet

I want to connect a mouse and a tablet to the same computer.

I want the mouse's cursor to be *separate* from the cursor used by the tablet.

Is there a way to make two pointing devices control two separate mouse cursors on Windows 7?

Comment: Can you also have two mouse devices? That would be super cool

Comment: I'd be more than surprised if Windows were able to show more than one pointer.

Comment: Perhaps this SU question might help: http://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor

Answer (score 1):

You can try Microsoft's [Multipoint](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/multipoint/) . Its basically used in educational institutions to cut down on hardware costs .
Or you can use [MultiMouse](http://www.multimouse.com/) but they very clearly express that you need more than one machine and is more of a collaborative tool .
I guess Microsoft doesnot pose any such restriction so you can go for it although I think at $139 the price is a bit steep

You can also try [Wunderworks](http://www.wunderworks.com/)  (sadly this is paid too ) 
All these tools allow multiple mouse points , might also work with tablet .
 Couldn't find any mention of any other input devices besides mouse and keyboard though.

Comment: Wunderworks is not a full solution - two pointers but only one window could have focus and do events

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [TeamPlayer](http://www.webtlk.com/2008/12/19/how-to-install-multiple-mice-mouse-and-keyboards-on-the-same-computer/) software would suit your needs.

From the website:

> TeamPlayer is an easy, free software which lets you connect two or
>   more mice and keyboards to the same computer. Does it look tricky to
>   understand? Here are the easy steps to make you achieve this amazing
>   result.

1. Plug-in your spare mouse and keyboard to your computer.
2. Install TeamPlayer on your PC.
3. Take control of your mice right away.

> That’s it!
>
> TeamPlayer comes in two licences. The first one is a commercial
>   licence you have to pay for. The second one is a private licence which
>   is completely for free, but with just one limitation: you can not
>   connect more than 2 users and with limited functionality.

See: [dicolab.com](http://www.dicolab.com)

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding the answer.  Just pointing to a product isn't considered an answer by current standards because it doesn't indicate anything about why it's a good solution or how to accomplish the solution.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/)
- [MaxiVista](http://www.maxivista.com/)
- [Input Director](http://www.inputdirector.com/)

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding the answer.  Just pointing to a product isn't considered an answer by current standards because it doesn't indicate anything about why it's a good solution or how to accomplish the solution.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Thanks.