# Is it possible to have two pointers (cursors) on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, mouse-cursor

Is there a software out there that will allow two mouse pointers (cursors) on my Mac? Note that I don't just want to connect two *mice*, I want two *pointers,* each controlled by a mouse. This is the Mac version of [this question.](https://superuser.com/questions/29432/using-two-mice-in-windows-7-dual-mouse-dual-cursor)

Comment: If there's only one pointing device connected, how are you planning on controlling the second pointer?

Comment: How are you going to control the second pointer without another mouse?  This is NOT the equivalent of that question at all.

Comment: Whoops, lemme fix that. Check back in a sec...

Comment: btw, mouse pointer and cursor are different things. Cursor is normally used to refer to the caret (text insertion point) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret

Comment: @Steven I know, I was trying to make it less confusing. Should I take that out?

Comment: I think this is the closest you'll get. It hasn't been updated since 2006... http://multicursor-wm.sourceforge.net/

Comment: For me the most interesting part of this question is "Why do you want two mouse pointers in the first place? what's the point?"

Comment: @heiglandreas So that I can use two monitors, and have two people using one computer at the same time. :)

Comment: Can you explain why you want to have two people using the same computer at the same time, but you ***don't*** want to have two mice?

Answer (score 1):

Vine Server, for one, lets you set up a VNC server on a single user basis; you can then fast-switch to another user locally, and allow the original user to connect via VNC to their active desktop.

Comment: Very good answer. However, it still requires having *two* computers. The whole point is to have two people on one, single computer :)