# How to change mouse to left handed but keep touchpad right handed in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, mouse, touchpad

Windows 10 had a 'Mouse Properties' window; if you had multiple mouse drivers installed, each device would show up in a separate tab allowing you to set left and right mouse buttons independently.

Windows 11 has 'Mouse settings' that has a global primary mouse button setting. This can be set to Left  or Right.

'Mouse Properties' has moved under 'Additional Mouse Settings', There is a 'Hardware' tab, and I can see both 'HID-Compliant mouse' and 'Synaptics Precision Touchpad Filter Driver' listed. I can hilight either one of these drivers, but if I switch back to the 'Buttons' tab, changing the button changes the buttons for both devices.

Similar to

- [How to change mouse to left handed but keep touchpad right handed?](https://superuser.com/questions/907216/how-to-change-mouse-to-left-handed-but-keep-touchpad-right-handed)
- [Two mice, one left handed and another right handed. At the same time](https://superuser.com/questions/439642/two-mice-one-left-handed-and-another-right-handed-at-the-same-time)

The solutions suggested there don't work in windows 11, except for EitherMouse, downloadable at https://eithermouse.com/, which is an unsigned binary.

If there is a way to choose mouse buttons per pointing device through settings, I would like to know how to do that. If not, is there a signed 3rd party program that will allow me to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with EitherMouse, and why are you still looking for more products?

Comment: I prefer to use signed binaries; doubly so when it comes to input devices.

Comment: There aren't too many products like that, as digital licenses cost money so you wouldn't find them in free products. Here are some free products that you could check for having a signed executable: [MouseMux](https://www.mousemux.com/), [PluralInput](https://pluralinput.com/index-old.html), [TeamPlayer 2](https://www.actualidadgadget.com/en/teamplayer-2-how-to-use-two-mice-on-a-single-computer/). They all have paid versions, so might be signed.